# Method to detect if I'm in text or html view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm creating a multipart part mail with the view `my_email.html.erb` and `my_email.text.erb`

I'm using shared helper methods to which I want to tell if the view is text or html, how can I do this?

Comment: are  you looking to do something like in your view call helper foo() and inside foo, get the name of the template and see if .html.erb or .text.erb an do something different in the helper?.  If so why not just pass in content type to the helper?

Comment: @Doon How do I find out the content_type in the view?

Comment: unless I am mistaken you would be calling the helper from the .erb file, so you should know the content type by nature of the file you are editing?

Comment: LOL! Thanks a lot Doon, I guess I'm tired...